# sass/bulma error : Error: File to import not found or unreadable: utilities/mixins.sass

Tags: css, sass, bulma

]I am trying to compile a css file from sass. I am using bulma (bulma.io) as the css framework. Here is the directory structure I have [image]

I am trying to change the grid.sass to output.css

and I am running this command from the "bulma" dir

```
 sass grid.sass output.css
```

but I get the following error

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: utilities/mixins.sass.
        on line 1 of grid.sass
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

I don't know why this error is appearing. I am running this according the documentation. I am on CentOs machine, and have gem installed.

```
[root@foo bulma]# sass -v
Sass 3.4.23 (Selective Steve)
```

Comment: try `@import "utilities/mixins"` without `.sass` other files you import as well

Comment: Hmm.. have you checked the file permissions of the "utilities" directory? This shouldn't be the case, but have you tried to change the filename mixins.sass to _mixins.sass or the `@import "utilities/mixins.sass"` to `@import "utilities/mixins"`. Check also if adding semicolons after each import line changes anything: `@import "utilities/mixins";`

Comment: @dippas I tried removing the `.sass` part but I get the same error.

Comment: @Picard adding semicolon produces another error `Error: Invalid @import: expected end of line, was ";".`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with the sass gem, however according to their docs, you would not use quotes and add semicolons. So I assume something like:

`@import utilities/mixins;`

[Import - Sass Docs](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5-Sass)

You might also need to rename your grid file to have an underscore, as mentioned in their docs as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting similar error in when I was using `bulma-extensions`. To fix it, I had to update the import statement from

```
@import 'bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass'
```

to this.

```
@import '../../bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass'
```

Note: I installed `sass-loader` and `node-sass` in `vue-cli` generated project.